# EditText return back previously input data after pressed back button

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an application login system type of application. 
Once the user pressed back button after login, the username and password EditText are filled with what the user enter just now. Is there any way to clear the EditText to empty? Sorry that if I make this sounds confusing. Any comment will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this by overriding `onPause` method of Activity and in onPause method clear all EditText Value as:

```
@Override
 protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();

         // Clear all value here
        editTextone.setText("");
        editTexttwo.setText("");
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`et.setText("");` inside `onResume()` to set empty text on immediate start.

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `edittext.setText("");`

Or alternatively you could use `edittext.setText(null)`

Answer (score 0):

manually clear all the editText using this in `onResume`

```
edtText.setText("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess this will solve your problem.

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    username.setText("");
    EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    password.setText("");

}
```