# Preserve edittext entry after pressing onOptionsItemSelected

Tags: java, android

Hello I have the reverse of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119158/edittext-return-back-previously-input-data-after-pressed-back-button) problem, all my entries disappear.

I want to retain the entries in the EditText after selecting a menu button. Here is my code. Do i have to pass intents if I want to preserve my information?

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.seeSavedRoutes:
        Intent launchNewIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SavedRoutes.class);
        startActivityForResult(launchNewIntent, 0);
        super.onPause();
        onPause();
        return true;            
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `super.onPause()` and `onPause()` inside it ? What happens when you remove them?

Comment: Try with onResume() instead of onPause().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't explicit call `onPause`, it will be called by android system.
All android widgets save and restore state by default (NOTE: In order for the Android system to restore the state of the views in your activity, each view must have a unique ID, supplied by the android:id attribute.).
Also you may save additional state (or state of views without id) in `onSaveInstanceState` and restore it in `onCreate(Bundle)` or in `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)`.
Please, read: [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29)

Comment: Thanks, I removed the onPauses and it works. Thanks for the documentation as well.